# Needs to understand .init_array section

Tags: assembly, x86, g++, gnu

I am new to x86 assembly, Please help me with the .init_array basic understandings. I have searched docs online for 5 hours but didn't find any useful docs for an explanation.

```
 3240 Disassembly of section .init_array:
 3241   
 3242 0000000000602dc0 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>:
 3243   602dc0:   90                      nop
 3244   602dc1:   1f                      (bad)  
 3245   602dc2:   40 00 00                add    %al,(%rax)
 3246   602dc5:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 3247   602dc7:   00 e0                   add    %ah,%al
 3248   602dc9:   1c 40                   sbb    $0x40,%al
 3249   602dcb:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 3250   602dcd:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 3251   602dcf:   00 50 1e                add    %dl,0x1e(%rax)
 3252   602dd2:   40 00 00                add    %al,(%rax)
 3253   602dd5:   00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
 3254     ...
```

The above code is dumped by objdump of libc++ library.

Question One：In the above code, what do al and rax representing? What are the operations trying to achieve? And on line 3254, why there is a '''...''' here?

Question Two: I see some people post their .init_array looks like the following:

```
Disassembly of section .init_array:

c1008db4 <.init_array>:
c1008db4:   c1000000    .word   0xc1000000
c1008db8:   c1000a68    .word   0xc1000a68
c1008dbc:   c1000b64    .word   0xc1000b64
c1008dc0:   c1000c04    .word   0xc1000c04
c1008dc4:   c1000c68    .word   0xc1000c68
```

```
What are they representing? Why mine is totally different from his/her.
```

Question Three: What are the things to put into the .init_array?

Question Four: I know all the function pointers of class constructors go into .init_array. But what is the reason for it?

Thanks!!

Comment: As they are pointers you should not disassemble as code. The reason is to have a way to specify functions that need to be called at program start.

Comment: Thanks Jester, How could I properly disassemble a binary or library? What I use is objdump -DS glic.so.6

Comment: `-D` specifically stands for disassemling everything including sections that don't normally contain code such as your `.init_array`.